# unknown attribute 'name' for Student for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have two model class called Student and Parent. I am trying to upload a CSV file that allow me to use Parent attributes: name, email and etc into Student model class or its CSV file. When I run my code I get the error message unknown attribute 'name' for Student. I do understand why I am getting this error message because the attributes name is not in Student attributes but only in the Parent class. I need guidance on how to add parent attributes into my Student model class correctly. I can export the Parent attributes with the Student Attributes on the same CSV file but when I import those CSV file I get the error message I mention early. Any help would be appreciated.

Student.rb Model Class:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  delegate :email,:name,:phone_number,to: :parent, allow_nil: true


  def self.to_csv
    attributes = %w{parent_id name first_name last_name  age workshop interest registration_date email   }
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      csv << attributes

      all.each do |script|
        csv << attributes.map{ |attr| script.send(attr) }
      end
    end

  end

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
    header=spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
      row = Hash[[header,spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    #CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

      student = find_by_id(row["id"])|| new
      student.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*row.to_hash.keys)
      student.save!
    end
  end


  def self.open_spreadsheet(file)
    case File.extname(file.original_filename)
    when ".csv" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
    when ".xls" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
    when ".xlsx" then Roo::CSV.new(file.path)
    else raise "Unknown file type: #{file.original_filename}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I've done this same thing, the importing/exporting to excel using Roo. There should really be a library that lets us `class MyModel; excel_importable; excel_exportable; end` and then it has all of this taken care of. Anybody have some free time and want to do that? ;)

Comment: @alexanderbird were you able to import your file correctly

Comment: @ndn I am getting the same error message: unknown attribute 'name' for Student.

Comment: yes, I was, but I didn't have any association going on. I'm assuming yours works if you only update student attributes?

Comment: @alexanderbird Unfortunately, i am receiving an error message:Validation failed: Parent can't be blank, Parent can't be blank, First name can't be blank, First name can't be blank, Last name can't be blank, Last name can't be blank, Age can't be blank, Age can't be blank, Workshop can't be blank, Workshop can't be blank, Interest can't be blank, Interest can't be blank, Registration date can't be blank, Registration date can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email can't be blank, Email Not a valid email format

Comment: I doubt this is all of it, but should you be adding `allow_empty: true` in your delegate statement? Also, if I were you, I would try to get only one attribute importing. I would make a csv that has columns only for id and a string attribute on the Student object, and try importing that. Once that works, I would add support for the rest of the columns. I'm wondering: is the problem you're experiencing because the import doesn't work period or because it doesn't work with the association?

Comment: @alexanderbird how do I make a csv that has columns only for id and a string attribute on the Student object, and try importing that. can you give me an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109727/discussion-between-alexanderbird-and-user2803053).

Answer (score 1):

You have `name` in the list of attributes you are pulling from `Student`

```
def self.to_csv
   attributes = %w{parent_id name # <--
```

When you run the following code, `name` is one of the columns sent as `attr`

```
all.each do |script|
  csv << attributes.map{ |attr| script.send(attr) }
end
```

And `script` is one instance of `Student` from your call to `all`

The issue is that you have used `script` as your variable name in that block, where it should be `student`, which has confused you.

To fix it, alter `self.to_csv` inside the `Student` class, so that the `attributes` listed are just the ones for `Student`. If you're only interested in database column values, you could use `attributes = column_names` so that `ActiveRecord` will provide them to you in a handy array.

Comment: thanks for the respond, so are saying that I need to place student inside the bracket and remove script.

Comment: I change the name from script to student, however I get the same error message: unknown attribute 'name' for Student.